# Invalid update of a UIDatePicker inside tableView crashing in iOS 13 on rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uidatepicker, xcode11.3

I am adding a UIDatePicker as a table's footer. I have another extension of UITableView which implements *traitCollectionDidChange* and only does beginUpdates and endUpdates. I am getting the below crash on changing the orientation.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIPickerTableView _Bug_Detected_In_Client_Of_UITableView_Invalid_Number_Of_Rows_In_Section:],
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3901.4.2/UITableView.m:2407
2020-05-12 13:35:28.729340+0530 MyApplication[41892:1575639] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. 
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of 
rows contained in that section before the update (10000), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or 
deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into 
or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c70ff8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff256e9b51 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4825d508 -[UITableView _Bug_Detected_In_Client_Of_UITableView_Invalid_Number_Of_Rows_In_Section:] + 193
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4825cdc1 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 16657
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48276e0b -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 112
    7   MyApplication                        0x0000000103d13ed1 -[UITableView(RIAdditions) traitCollectionDidChange:] + 97
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4854ccc4 -[UIView _traitCollectionDidChangeInternal:] + 977
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4854d5c4 -[UIView _wrappedProcessTraitCollectionDidChange:forceNotification:] + 161
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4854d80a -[UIView _wrappedProcessTraitCollectionDidChange:forceNotification:] + 743
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4854d80a -[UIView _wrappedProcessTraitCollectionDidChange:forceNotification:] + 743
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4854d80a -[UIView _wrappedProcessTraitCollectionDidChange:forceNotification:] + 743
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4854d80a -[UIView _wrappedProcessTraitCollectionDidChange:forceNotification:] + 743
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4854d80a -[UIView _wrappedProcessTraitCollectionDidChange:forceNotification:] + 743
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4854d7ae -[UIView _wrappedProcessTraitCollectionDidChange:forceNotification:] + 651
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4854d935 -[UIView _processDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:forceNotification:] + 140
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff485783d2 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2243
    18  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b131db1 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 255
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b137fa3 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 517
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48563635 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 980
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47978038 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 1465
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff479710e9 -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewControllerLookForNested:] + 589
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47966e9a __105-[UINavigationController _repositionPaletteWithNavigationBarHidden:duration:shouldUpdateNavigationItems:]_block_invoke + 718
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47966b9c -[UINavigationController _repositionPaletteWithNavigationBarHidden:duration:shouldUpdateNavigationItems:] + 308
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47970339 -[UINavigationController _updateBarsForCurrentInterfaceOrientationAndForceBarLayout:] + 174
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47980763 __84-[UINavigationController willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:]_block_invoke + 639
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a42124 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] + 294
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a3e446 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext __runAlongsideAnimations] + 263
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4856bde6 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 528
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4856c395 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 99
    31  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a5665a __58-[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 + 278
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4856ff44 +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:forScene:] + 174
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a563e8 __58-[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 164
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4856bde6 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 528
    35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4856c395 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 99
    36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a562c0 -[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:] + 491
    37  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480d2e9d -[UIWindow _rotateToBounds:withAnimator:transitionContext:] + 525
    38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480d58e0 -[UIWindow _rotateWindowToOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:skipCallbacks:] + 2331
    39  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480d5ed3 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 633
    40  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480d4e27 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 119
    41  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480d3ca4 __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 111
    42  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480d3bcd -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 455
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b9b5bc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b9aa35 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 421
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b9a7a1 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 193
    46  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c988b3 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1811
    47  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b9a0f6 _CFXNotificationPost + 950
    48  Foundation                          0x00007fff2574bbf7 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 59
    49  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47cd5955 -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 224
    50  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c83f1 __134-[_UIWindowSceneDeviceOrientationSettingsDiffAction _updateDeviceOrientationWithSettingObserverContext:windowScene:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 137
    51  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47bd8c83 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 865
    52  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47cd2dff _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 240
    53  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c8336 -[_UIWindowSceneDeviceOrientationSettingsDiffAction _updateDeviceOrientationWithSettingObserverContext:windowScene:transitionContext:] + 248
    54  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c8231 __163-[_UIWindowSceneDeviceOrientationSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 112
    55  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47cd2d02 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 84
    56  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c80c1 -[_UIWindowSceneDeviceOrientationSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 216
    57  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff476206e7 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 657
    58  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4761f26c -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 248
    59  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47620411 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 210
    60  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47bfac66 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 504
    61  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365d6c07 -[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 565
    62  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365fc99f __88-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:updateWithSettingsDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 123
    63  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365e0c45 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 220
    64  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365fc8dc __88-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:updateWithSettingsDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 196
    65  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010610ed48 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    66  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106111cb9 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    67  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662237e __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    68  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662206c -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441
    69  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662257b -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    70  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd4471 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    71  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd439c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    72  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd3b74 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    73  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce87f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    74  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce066 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    75  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff384c0bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    76  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48092d4d UIApplicationMain + 1621
    77  MyApplication                        0x00000001041a68db main + 107
    78  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5227ec25 start + 1
    79  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I found out that this crash happens specifically due to datePicker(or may be the table inside it) i.e. UIPickerTableView. Code crashes at line self.endUpdates() for UIPickerTableView. Please find the code of the dummy app I created:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        self.tableView.tableFooterView = datePicker

    }
}

extension UITableView {

    open override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        self.beginUpdates()
        self.endUpdates()
    }

}
```

Would be glad if anyone could help me understand the root cause of this crash.

Comment: Take a look at [mre] ... see if you can reproduce the crash in a simple, stripped-down example. If so, then edit your question and include the needed code.

Comment: Thanks @DonMag for the suggestion. I have created a small app with basic table and datePicker to replicate the crash. Updated the question with required code.

Comment: Hmmm... curious... Using your code as posted does not crash for me (Xcode 11.4.1, Swift 5, iPhone 8 simulator iOS 13.4.1). More curious, `traitCollectionDidChange` is not even called when I add your `extension UITableView`?

Comment: Wow, that's strange. First of all thanks for trying. I now wonder if this is an iOS 13.3 bug and fixed in iOS 13.4? I am using Xcode 11.3 though. Maybe I will check in iOS 13.4 and update you.

Comment: OK - on an iPhone 7 (device) with iOS 13.3, I **do** get the crash. `traitCollectionDidChange` in your extension is called 10 times... which means so are the calls to `begin/end Updates`. Commenting those out -- no more crash. Using that extension seems a little odd to begin with, though. Are you sure you need it? Or that that's the best way to implement it?

Comment: In general, you call begin/end updates to let the tableView know you've changed something and it needs to re-render affected cells. I'd be very surprised if that was necessary (or even accomplished anything) on trait change.

Comment: Yeah, even I think it should be removed. Good suggestion. Thanks for the explanation on  beginUpdates/endUpdates. Documentation discusses them individually and I did not find an answer regarding what plain begin-end do without any code b/w them. For now, I am able to get rid of the crash using the check ![[[self class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIPickerTableView"]). But I will get rid of that extension for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comments and some testing...

- the crash occurs on iOS 13.3, but not on iOS 13.4
- on iOS 13.4, `traitCollectionDidChange` in the extension is not even called
- on iOS 13.3, it **is** called, and in fact is called 10 times (my quick testing observation)

  - repeatedly calling `beginUpdates()` `endUpdates()` is causing the crash
  - those calls are probably (almost certainly) not needed to begin with

A little clarification on `beginUpdates()` `endUpdates()` ...

They tell the table view to process / animate changes to the table *without* reloading the cells. A common usage is for expanding / collapsing cells, using a "callback" closure.

Assume a custom cell with various UI elements, including an "Expand / Collapse" button. The code in `cellForRowAt` may look like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sCell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleCell
    c.myLabel.text = "\(indexPath)"
    c.callback = {
        c.myHeightConstraint.constant = c.myHeightConstraint.constant == 21 ? 60 : 21
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    return c
}
```

When the button is tapped in the cell, it calls back to the closure which toggles our cell's `myHeightConstraint` between 21 and 60. ***With*** those calls, we see the row's height animate. ***Without*** those calls, the row doesn't change height until something else tells the table view to re-caclulate / re-layout the rows.

Note that Apple's docs state those calls are being phased-out / deprecated in favor of `performBatchUpdates()`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sCell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleCell
    c.myLabel.text = "\(indexPath)"
    c.callback = {
        c.myHeightConstraint.constant = c.myHeightConstraint.constant == 21 ? 60 : 21
        tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
    }
    return c
}
```

will accomplish the same thing.

So, as those calls are not doing anything - other than *causing the crash* - it sounds like they should be removed.