# What are iOS-runtime-headers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to understand the concept of runtime-headers. I was resolving a crash in **UIDatePicker** and observed some classes that seem related to it; **UIPickerTableView** and **UIColumnView** are the ones. When I tried searching on google for these, I get results for iOS-runtime-headers and the source-code for those classes.

This is what I understand: Headers like UIView.h are exposed to developer for using the functionalities, hiding the actual implementation. I cannot relate this to UIPickerTableView at least because I wasn't even able to use it in Xcode. I get unidentified declaration error. But I see that UIDatePicker internally uses it.

I cannot connect these dots. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The headers dictate the public interface. As an application developer, you should only be interacting with these public interfaces. There are all sorts of private types, methods, etc., such as the ones you reference here, that are not exposed to us and you shouldn’t worry about them nor try to use them directly. In fact, if you attempt to use private API, your app will be rejected from the store. If you’re having trouble with a date picker, I’d suggest you post a separate question on that topic, and we’d be happy to help with that.

Comment: Thanks Rob, for the info. I do have another thread discussing my problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61746836/invalid-update-of-a-uidatepicker-inside-tableview-crashing-in-ios-13-on-rotation

Comment: I’d suggest you create a blank project and then add enough to manifest the your crash. Without reproducible example of the problem (including code), we are unlikely to be able to help you, unfortunately. (And, often, in the process of creating the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you’ll figure out what causes the problem yourself.)